# My php cron doesn't trigger

Tags: cron, debian

This is my crontab file (after `crontab -e`):

```
50 6,14,22 * * * php /var/www/web_hdef/public/artisan run:handler
0 6,14,22 * * * php /var/www/web_hdef/public/artisan run:endomondo
30 6,14,22 * * * php /var/www/web_hdef/public/artisan run:update
```

but it doesn't run and after `crontab -l` in command line I got:

```
hp /var/www/web_hdef/public/artisan run:updatedo(8)
```

I ran commands separately a they works

Comment: *Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `nano editor` I didn't see all of signs in text file, when I openned it in `vim editor`, I saw that there are extra white spaces. I removed it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `php` executable is not in `$PATH` of user running the script. Use absolute path

Comment: no it does not. the fact you checked in shell does not mean it works from cron. This is NOT the same env by default.